# Magento 2.2 Rest API not working for Sales Orders and Customers

Tags: api, rest-api, magento2.2

We are trying to get Customers and Sales Orders from Magento 2.2 Store using token.After creating API Username and Roles, with the same request we can retrieve products but not sales orders and customers.

```
public function getOrders()
{
    $searchCriteria = '?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]='.$this->from.'&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][value]='.$this->to.'&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][condition_type]=to';
    $requestUrl = $this->Url.$this->apiUrl.$this->orders.$searchCriteria;
    $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $this->token");
    $ch = curl_init();
    ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: No we are unable to resolve the issue...Please help us asap

Comment: Uncommented the below Rewrite Rule to resolve the issue:

# Workaround for HTTP authorization in CGI environment
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Comment: Where this we can find?? in Magento Settings? RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]